# Blackberry simulator and Facebook API error

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I've encountered a problem with the Facebook API for BB. I've got the latest FB jar.

When I run my (extremely basic) App I get a dialog popping up with this message:

"Error starting BBFacebook: Module 'BBFacebook' has verification error 2637 at offset 0220 (codfile version 79)"

I'd be most grateful if someone could point me in the right direstio for fixing this.

TIA

Comment: Stupid mistake - I neglected to add the Log jar.

Comment: please add your comment as answer and mark it as solve or just delete the question

Comment: some times we did mistake like this. means we don't add both jar files. If your answer is right, then write the answer by your own and mark as solved;

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake - I neglected to add the Log jar